# Dirt mound in center of crawl space - Why?

Tags: structural, crawlspace

[image]

There is a dirt mound towards the center of my crawl space area, and it drops of towards the foundation wall. Is this common, and what is the reason for it? My thoughts are possibly for flooding purposes so water does not reach the beam post supports. (I am in a high risk flooding area). Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Is that your native soil? It looks a lot like masonry sand.

Comment: Yeah I don't think it's my native soil. Could be masonry soil.

Comment: In the case of an actual flood, 6-8" of sand won't do much to ward off water, besides, the support post should be on a footing.